# IOS Close UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I open an UIPopoverController which is made of 3 buttons when the user click on a UITableViewCell. These buttons are vote buttons so when the user submit his vote, i want to close my UIPopoverController.

This is what i do :

```
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    myViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"val_vote"];
    self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:vc];
    self.popOver.delegate=self;

    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 10, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Is it possible to close this Popover when the user interacted with it ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

In the target methods of the buttons to vote you have to call

```
[yourViewControllerThatPresentedThePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```